# mesh - Matrix dimensions must agree

Tags: matlab, mesh

In matlab:

```
X = ones(10,10);
mesh(X,X,X);
```

gives:

```
Warning: Matrix dimensions must agree, not rendering mesh
```

All three parameters are exactly the same, but their dimensions do not agree? Agree to what? What is the problem? Thank you for your time & any help.

Comment: No warning on my system :-/

Comment: dito, no warning (13a). Which version do you use?

Comment: Restarted matlab .. it's now working. Matlab is sometimes such a headache! Thank you guys!

Comment: `rehash` and `rehash toolbox` would help too, I reckon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting matlab solved the problem.